# How to query firebase realtime database array and return the object representation instead of array

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

we inherited a old database structure w/c stores colors as arrays in firebase realtime database

[image]

As you can see from the figure, index `5` is missing since it was set to `null` and firebase don't store `null` values

The problem with this is as you can see, index number `5` is missing since firebase doesn't store the values of array elements with null values.

For example: `colorCodes[5] = null;`

The problem is when we fetch the colors, it returns an array value and loses it's correct index information.
Let's say i store the fetched colors in `colors` array and looking at `colors[5]` would then return a value since firebase just returns a simple array NOT containing the original  indexes.

Is there a way to return a object instead of array so it still points to the correct indexes so the color on index `5` would still return null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the intended behavior as explained in [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

> Firebase has no native support for arrays. If you store an array, it really gets stored as an "object" with integers as the key names.

```
// we send this
['hello', 'world']
// Firebase stores this
{0: 'hello', 1: 'world'}
```

So with your current structure you'll get an array:

```
["#D1FF61", "B9BEFF", ...]
```

*The order will be same as in the database.*

If you change your structure so each index stores an object like this:

[image]

This should return an array with both item index and value:

[image]

Do note that index 2 is empty as we have node in the response as well so it should be easier for your to process your array.

Also note that,

> // since the keys are numeric and sequential,
> // if we query the data, we get this ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>
> // however, if we then delete a, b, and d, // they are no longer
> mostly sequential, so // we do not get back an array {2: 'c', 4: 'e'}

To ease things, I would rather store a map instead of array with keys `hex1`, `hex2` and so on. Object with your expected structure can easily be formed using Javascript. If you still want to have arrays itself, then you should take a look at Firestore.

Comment: unfortunately, we have a very specific use case where we need to get the object representation of the array field. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer can you share a sample object that you are expecting?

Comment: basically the array is converted into { "0": "hex1", "1": "hex2", "4": "hex4" } where the original index is respected

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer as mentioned the index will be same in the retrieved array so hex1 will be at 0 and so on ... You can loop through the array `arr.forEach((hex, i) => myMap[i] = hex)` to get the object. But read the blog mentioned in answer, if you remove any key and it's no longer sequential it'll end up in an object instead of array.

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer as mentioned the index will be same in the retrieved array so hex1 will be at 0 and so on ... You can loop through the array `arr.forEach((hex, i) => myMap[i] = hex)` to get the object. But read the blog mentioned in answer, if you remove any key and it's no longer sequential it'll end up in an object instead of array.

Comment: indeed, just re-read the blog and you're correct; I've checked it through `Object.keys(colors)` and it indeed returns correctly the index. I was copying the value through `copy` command in `debugger` and it seems that `copy` command doesn't respect indexes.

Thanks a lot.